# How do I use a sling service in sightly page without using javascript?

Tags: java, sling, sightly

I have to use a sling service that I created e.g.

```
@Component
@Service
public class SearchServiceImpl implements SearchService {
    public SearchResults search() {
     SearchResults results = new SearchResults();
     .....
     return results;
    }
}
```

Now I want to call this service in my sightly without using javascript as there are chances some users wont use javascript while accessing my service. How do I call this service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go for the use API. This requires to provide a search component class that implements the WCMUse interface.

```
...
import com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUse;

public class Search extends WCMUse {

   @Reference
   private SearchService searchService

   public SearchResults listResults(){ 
   ...
```

The search component uses your service to get the actual results and provides the datamodel to the sightly template.

```
<div data-sly-use.search="Search">
    <ul data-sly-list.result="${search.listResults}">
      <li>${result.title}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The official documentation is quite helpful to achieve our goal.
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/use-api-in-java.html for details

Comment: In your example `Search` is not actually a component, so the `@Reference` annotation will not work.

Answer (score 2):

`@Reference` doesn't work in sightly. You have to use sling scripting helper class here.

Look at the snippet below:

```
public class Search extends WCMUse {

    SearchService service

    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {
        service = getSlingScriptHelper().getService( SearchService.class );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned Sling, and not AEM, you can directly get a reference to a service with `data-sly-use`. Have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-4554.

This will be available in AEM 6.2.

Answer (score 2):

In AEM 6.2 you can achieve this by simply putting the Service in the HTL code:

```html
<p data-sly-use.search="com.your.package.SearchServiceImpl">
   ${search.results}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best answer is to go for use of getSlingScriptHelper().getService() in WCMUSEPOJO class as per AEM 6.2

Below link is enough to explain it in better manner.

http://adobeaemclub.com/access-osgi-ser%C2%ADvice-from-the-wcmuse-class-in-sightly/